# Conflicting Packages with \begin{longtabu}? Why not breaking?

Tags: packages, page-breaking, longtabu

I am working on a very long document with countless formatting and package requirements. I am now all of a sudden having an issue with {longtabu} in a landscape environment. It is no longer breaking and spreading onto two pages. I did not change the code there at all. Additionally, the first page is black and simply says "Continued on next Page." The image below shows the second page where multiple headers are found and no page break occurring. It used to work with my code as shown in the second figure.

[image]

[image]

I'm thinking I added a package later that conflicts but I can't track it down. Here is a list of packages and the following MWE.

```
% ========== Preamble
\documentclass[11pt, proquest]{uwthesis}

\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=6

% Formatting packages
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=0pt} %remove space before {itemize}

% Table packages:
% Multi-page tables and rotating:
    \usepackage{longtable,rotating}
% Tables with paragraph-like columns
    %\usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{tabu}
% Thick vertical line option
    \newcolumntype{"}{!{\vrule width 1.5pt}}


% Math Packages

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thickhline}{%
\noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 1pt
\futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{center}
\scriptsize
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth { " X[0.65,m,c] " @{\hspace{-0.1in}}X[2.5,m,l]@{\hspace{0.2in}} | X[3,m,c] | X[3.5,m,c] " }
\caption{Previous Experimental Research Summary \label{tab:ExpLitSummary}}\\

    \thickhline
    Researcher & \centering Program Description & Setup & Proposed Equation \\
    \thickhline
    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- Continued from previous page} \\
    \thickhline
    Researcher & \centering Program Description & Setup & Proposed Equation \\
    \thickhline
    \endhead

    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Continued on next page} \\
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot    

    \singlespacing {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Blah}} & \begin{itemize} \item Blah
    \item Blah
    \item Blah, $f_c^{\prime}$, and $P/P_o$
    \item Blah \end{itemize} & {\rule{1cm}{3cm}}
    & \tiny{\vspace{-0.2in}\begin{gather}
    \textbf{Pure~Shear~Capacity~(a/D~=~0):} \nonumber\\ 
    V_0 = A_cf_{cv}+A_sf_{yv} = 2A_cf_{ct}+0.6A_sf_s \nonumber \\ 
    \nonumber \end{gather} \vspace{-0.4in}}\\

    \thickhline

    \singlespacing {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Blah}} & \vspace{0.15in}\begin{itemize} \item Blah
    \item Blah
    \item Blah
    \item Blah \end{itemize} & {\rule{1cm}{3cm}}
    & \begin{gather}
    V_0 = V_{0(Xiao)}\left(1+\Phi\right) \nonumber \\
    \nonumber \end{gather} \\

    \thickhline

    \singlespacing {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Blah}} & \begin{itemize} \item Blah 
    \item Blah
    \item Blah $P/P_o$
    \item Blah \end{itemize}  & {\rule{1cm}{3cm}} \qquad {\rule{1cm}{3cm}}
    & \tiny{\begin{gather}
    \mathbf{For~<a/D<0.5~and~P/(F_{yt}A_s+f_c^{\prime} A_c)\leq 0.4:} \nonumber\\
    \nonumber \end{gather}} \\

    \thickhline

    \singlespacing {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Blah}} & \begin{itemize} \item Blah
    \item Blah
    \item Blah $f_c^{\prime}$ and $P/P_o$
    \item Blah \end{itemize}  & {\rule{1cm}{3cm}}
    & \vspace{-0.2in} \tiny{\begin{gather}
    \textbf{Using~JapanRec:} \nonumber \\
    V_n = V_s+V_c \nonumber \\
    \nonumber \end{gather} \vspace{-0.4in}}\\

    \thickhline 

    \singlespacing {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Blah}} & \begin{itemize} \item Blah
    \item Blah (4.72 in.)
    \item Blah $A_s/A_c$), $f_c^{\prime}$, and $P/P_o$
    \item Blah \end{itemize}  & {\rule{1cm}{3cm}}
    & \tiny{\vspace{-0.25in} \begin{gather}
    \textbf{Using~DBJ/T13-51-2010:} \nonumber \\
    When~\frac{P}{P_0} \geq 2\eta_0 \sqrt[2.4]{1-\left(\frac{V}{V_{0}}\right)^2}, \nonumber \\
    \nonumber \end{gather}\vspace{-0.4in}}\\

    \thickhline
\end{longtabu}
\end{center}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: really it's impossible to say what is wrong with your table, if you do not show any code for the table.

Comment: `fixltx2e` is not needed any longer, by the way

Comment: Also, no need to load `array` twice, no need to load `color` when `xcolor` is already loaded, and no need for `epstopdf`.

Comment: My table script is very long and complicated, as it includes figures, lengthy equation, lists, etc. I did not feel it necessary to include, as it worked previously and no modifications were made to the file between working and not. I use a main file to compile chapters and this chapter was left untouched for a week between working and not working. I likely added a package for another chapter though that would affect this. Otherwise working a different file/chapter would have no effect on this table. I can post though if you'd like.

Comment: you can easily make a small example that shows the problem starting from a copy of your document. delete all the text apart from the table, replace each image by `\rule{1cm}{3cm}` or whatever size suitable, delete every package from the preamble that can be deleted while still showing the [roblem, then post the result,

Comment: You need to minimise the code to find the problem. Not all of those packages can be required. (If the problem really disappears if `fixltx2e` is removed, there's your problem solved since it is no longer needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - is there a package required for \rule{1cm}{3cm} - I cannot get it to run when trying to replace figures

Comment: @aheid no it's a core latex command defined in the format. or you can keep \includegraphics but use `{example-image}` which is in tex distributions for exactly that use.

Comment: I found my mistake there, thanks @DavidCarlisle. You will see I updated the script so it is much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `\thickhline` command defined here does not allow page breaking, using `\hline` allows the table to break normally (I also removed the `center` which can not center a longtable and just adds spurious space)

Note that `\tiny{...}` is a strange markup as `\tiny` doesn't take an argument, mostly it works here as the font change is restricted by the table cell, and the extra `{}` group is mostly harmless.

```
\documentclass[11pt, proquest]{uwthesis}

\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=6

% Formatting packages
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=0pt} %remove space before {itemize}

% Table packages:
% Multi-page tables and rotating:
    \usepackage{longtable,rotating}
% Tables with paragraph-like columns
    %\usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{tabu}
% Thick vertical line option
    \newcolumntype{"}{!{\vrule width 1.5pt}}


% Math Packages

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thickhline}{%
\noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 1pt
\futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}


\scriptsize
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth { " X[0.65,m,c] " @{\hspace{-0.1in}}X[2.5,m,l]@{\hspace{0.2in}} | X[3,m,c] | X[3.5,m,c] " }
\caption{Previous Experimental Research Summary \label{tab:ExpLitSummary}}\\

    \hline
    Researcher & \centering Program Description & Setup & Proposed Equation \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- Continued from previous page} \\
    \hline
    Researcher & \centering Program Description & Setup & Proposed Equation \\
    \hline
    \endhead

    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Continued on next page} \\
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot    

    \singlespacing {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Blah}} & \begin{itemize} \item Blah
    \item Blah
    \item Blah, $f_c^{\prime}$, and $P/P_o$
    \item Blah \end{itemize} & {\rule{1cm}{3cm}}
    & \tiny{\vspace{-0.2in}\begin{gather}
    \textbf{Pure~Shear~Capacity~(a/D~=~0):} \nonumber\\ 
    V_0 = A_cf_{cv}+A_sf_{yv} = 2A_cf_{ct}+0.6A_sf_s \nonumber \\ 
    \nonumber \end{gather} \vspace{-0.4in}}\\

    \hline

    \singlespacing {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Blah}} & \vspace{0.15in}\begin{itemize} \item Blah
    \item Blah
    \item Blah
    \item Blah \end{itemize} & {\rule{1cm}{3cm}}
    & \begin{gather}
    V_0 = V_{0(Xiao)}\left(1+\Phi\right) \nonumber \\
    \nonumber \end{gather} \\

    \hline

    \singlespacing {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Blah}} & \begin{itemize} \item Blah 
    \item Blah
    \item Blah $P/P_o$
    \item Blah \end{itemize}  & {\rule{1cm}{3cm}} \qquad {\rule{1cm}{3cm}}
    & \tiny{\begin{gather}
    \mathbf{For~<a/D<0.5~and~P/(F_{yt}A_s+f_c^{\prime} A_c)\leq 0.4:} \nonumber\\
    \nonumber \end{gather}} \\

    \hline

    \singlespacing {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Blah}} & \begin{itemize} \item Blah
    \item Blah
    \item Blah $f_c^{\prime}$ and $P/P_o$
    \item Blah \end{itemize}  & {\rule{1cm}{3cm}}
    & \vspace{-0.2in} \tiny{\begin{gather}
    \textbf{Using~JapanRec:} \nonumber \\
    V_n = V_s+V_c \nonumber \\
    \nonumber \end{gather} \vspace{-0.4in}}\\

    \hline 

    \singlespacing {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Blah}} & \begin{itemize} \item Blah
    \item Blah (4.72 in.)
    \item Blah $A_s/A_c$), $f_c^{\prime}$, and $P/P_o$
    \item Blah \end{itemize}  & {\rule{1cm}{3cm}}
    & \tiny{\vspace{-0.25in} \begin{gather}
    \textbf{Using~DBJ/T13-51-2010:} \nonumber \\
    When~\frac{P}{P_0} \geq 2\eta_0 \sqrt[2.4]{1-\left(\frac{V}{V_{0}}\right)^2}, \nonumber \\
    \nonumber \end{gather}\vspace{-0.4in}}\\

    \hline
\end{longtabu}


\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Removing \thickhline did it, thank you. However, I have evidence that the \thickline was fine before...the image above uses it. However, I may be mistaken (I am writing my thesis at hyperspeed) and am just happy this works now. Thanks for you r patience and the tips on center and \tiny, as well. I definitely do not always know the proper usage, just when something works of course.